# Was there any Agents of SHIELD tie-in to Civil War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, agents-of-shield, captain-america-civil-war

When the last few MCU movies came out, there had been corresponding sequences and tie-ins with the ongoing *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* series.  *Winter Soldier*'s introduction of Hydra-within-SHIELD fell right into lockstep with the series' traitor plotline.  *Thor 2* lead into the series' team having to do cleanup in the UK.  *Age of Ultron* revealed that Coulson's super-secret plan was actually readying a SHIELD Helicarrier for Fury's use.

Now, I admit that I sped through the last six episodes of *S.H.I.E.L.D.* in preparation for watching *Civil War* this weekend, so maybe I missed something.  However, I didn't notice any particular lead up to anything revealed in the movie this time around.  Did I miss anything?  Yes, I caught the cute little reference of HIVE/Ward saying "Only billionaires can have super suits and only the government can make super soldiers, which will lead to a war of its own", but was that it?  Did anything else from the series have any impact or cause any revelations in the movie?

Regarding the question [Which Marvel TV episodes are related to the MCU movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106158/which-marvel-tv-episodes-are-related-to-the-mcu-movies) that question is from 7 months ago and does not address the movie that came out this weekend.

Comment: @JasonBaker I'm not sure how I feel about that... On the one hand, that question might answer this question *in the future*. On the other hand, it doesn't appear to currently do so.

Comment: Reportedly, tomorrow's episode will deal with the fallout from *Civil War*

Comment: What we really need is some way to request an update on the other answer, if that's the way we think the information should be presented. As it stands, there's a design flaw in the SO system if we close this as a dupe.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens I've updated my answer to include the information currently available; in the general case, anyone could edit the answer (or post a new answer) to keep it up to date

Comment: Yeah, but this question is the missing piece in the system - the REQUEST to update the answer. In most cases, it seems like this would be closed as a dupe before the answer is updated. There should be another state like "Possible Merge Candidate".

Comment: Or, it's also possible that the original question is overly broad, and should target specific movies / television shows to avoid this problem.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens It's entirely possible that, since the MCU (including its TV series) is constantly growing, having a single question isn't the most effective way to organise the information and ensure that it's kept up to date as best as possible. Maybe start a discussion on meta about it?

Comment: I think you're probably right. I mean, isn't that going to be the mother of all list questions? Let's tackle this in meta...

Comment: The Agents of Shield series seems more of a setting the stage for the Inhuman film (look how much is being tweaked from the comics), with an in passing link to the film's as a means of chronological indexing

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens You can request a better answer to the other question in multiple ways: leave a comment on an existing answer that you think could be improved, put a bounty on the question with a note saying what you're looking for, create a meta question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Not yet, but there will be.**

Here's the official description of tomorrow's episode, "Emancipation", in spoiler quotes:

> In the aftermath of the events of Captain America: Civil War, S.H.I.E.L.D. feels pressure to reveal their involvement with Inhumans. But with the stakes higher than ever and Hive growing stronger, the team is tested in ways they could never anticipate.

Indeed, the second sneak-peak is of a conversation that relates *directly* to the events of *Captain America: Civil War*:

Although, if I had to wager, that'll be about the extent of it…

There has been no evident tie-in before this.