# Does AIDA create a sling-ring portal?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield, doctor-strange-2016

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 4, Phil Coulson, Leo Fitz, and Robbie Reyes are trapped in some other dimension. In order to get them out, the android AIDA creates a portal similar to the ones created by *Doctor Strange*'s sling rings. It looks quite similar, and achieves the same purpose. Is this coincidental, or was this on purpose?

Comment: That was the first episode after the _Doctor Strange_ US opening weekend, so I can't imagine it being coincidence.  There's another parallel as well, in the following episode, though it's a bit less obvious.

Comment: In essence it appears it is just a different means of creating a "sling ring portal" yes. We see the same at the end of the season with the one Ghost Rider creates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comics, [The Book of Cagliostro](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Book_of_Cagliostro) was copied from the [Darkhold](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Darkhold). This would be an explicit connection between the magic of the sling rings, and AIDA’s Darkhold-tech portal machine. Unfortunately, this association is not quite as explicit in the MCU.

In any case, even if that connection is never validated in the MCU, it is clear AIDA’s Darkhold-tech portal machine is based on MCU magic, and therefore of the name nature as Strange’s sling-ring portals.

Further cementing the connection is when Radcliffe described the Quantum Battery to Mace, it certainly sounded like the magical process described by the Ancient One.